# Conditional Expectation Properties

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $G$ a finite group of measurable, bijective maps $g: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ which are $P$ invariant, i.e. they have the property $P(g^{-1}(A)) = P(A) \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{F}$, and define $$\mathcal{C}_G \equiv \{A \in \mathcal{F}: g(A) = A \quad \forall g \in G\}$$

It is trivially seen that $\mathcal{C}_G$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.  I want to show the following: $$\textbf{(I)} \quad \quad E(X | \mathcal{C}_G) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} X \circ g(\omega) \quad P-\text{a.s.}$$

---

My attempt:  Define $Y$ as the RHS of **(I)**. It is easily shown that $E(Y1_A) = E(X1_A) \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{C}_G$ so it suffices to show that the RHS is $\mathcal{C}_G$ measurable.  And for this we simply need to show that $X \circ g$ is $\mathcal{C}_G$ measurable for each $g \in G$.  I don't really know how to do this, because what I need to prove is the following:

Fix $g \in G$ and then show $\forall h \in G$,

$$h(g^{-1}(X^{-1}(B))) = g^{-1}(X^{-1}(B))$$

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any $g_1 \in G$ we have $Y\circ g_1 =Y [P] \,  a.s.$ since $\{gg_1: g
\in G\}=G$. This implies that $Y$ is  measurable w.r.t the $P-$ completion of $\mathcal C_G$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand this notation or any of this hint at all.  $Y \circ g_1 = Y$ $P$ almost surely implies that $g_1$ is the identity function almost surely, no?  I'm not seeing how this helps in solving the question as this isn't the case.  I'm sorry I'm obviously missing something substantial here

Comment: $Y$ is the particular random variable that you defined. $Y\circ g_1=Y$ does not imply that $g_1$ is then identity.

Comment: Ok I understand that this is true if $$\textbf{(II)} \quad \mathcal{S} \equiv \{g \circ g_1 : g \in G\} = G$$ for in that case $g_1^{-1}(Y^{-1}(B) = Y^{-1}(B) \implies g(Y^{-1}(B)) = Y^{-1}(B)$.  In order to prove **(II)**, we note that the LHS is clearly a subset of $G$ as $g \circ g_1 \in G$ since $G$ forms a group under function composition and $g_1^{-1} \in G$ so that $g \circ g_1^{-1} \in G$ so that $g = g \circ g_1^{-1} \circ g \in \mathcal{S}$.  Is this correct?

Comment: @qp212223 Yes, that is correct.